# Tmux is not able to distinguish between insert and shift-insert

Tags: vim, tmux, xterm, input

<kbd>Insert</kbd> when in xterm, gives `^[[2~` and,

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> gives `^[[2;1~`

All this is good until I start tmux.

Note that the `$TERM` variable remains the same, so this issue should not be related to terminfo.

Tmux when in xterm is not able to distinguish between <kbd>Insert</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> and both are read as `^[[2~`. Not only xterm, but tmux when started in a virtual console, exhibits the same behaviour.

I tried with and without `set -g xterm-keys on` in the tmux conf file, but to no avail. FWIW I am running tmux 1.8 on XTerm(296) and these are the overrides in my `.Xresources`

```
XTerm*VT100.Translations: #override \
Shift<Key>Insert: string("\033[2;1~") \n\
<Key>Insert: string("\033[2~")
```

This is really a pain because I want to map <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> in vim but can't do it in tmux.

Interestingly, when I run GNU screen in the same xterm, it easily distinguishes between <kbd>Insert</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd>. I'm starting to believe it's some wickedness in tmux and not my setup.

Does anyone know how to make tmux get the keys transparently just like how xterm gets it without mangling it up in the middle or is there something I am doing wrong?

Comment: The $TERM variable remaining the same does not rule it out. Is is a variant of "screen"? Also, have you tried without a `.Xresources`?

Answer (score 0):

The value of `TERM` is irrelevant.  As I pointed out in *[tmux doesn't passes correctly ctrl-shift-arrow sequences](http://tmux%20doesn't%20passes%20correctly%20ctrl-shift-arrow%20sequences)*, `tmux` has a table of xterm-style special keys which it knows about.  For this case, the table `xterm_keys_table` has an entry for insert:

```
    { KEYC_IC,      "\033[2;_~" },
```

which means that it normally converts any of the variations with a parameter where you see the underscore `"_"` into the same value:

```
\033[2;2~
\033[2;3~
\033[2;4~
\033[2;5~
\033[2;6~
\033[2;7~
\033[2;8~
```

The way to change this is with the `xterm-keys` setting:

> **`xterm-keys`** *[on | off]*
>   If this option is set, `tmux` will generate xterm(1)-style 
>   function key sequences; these have a number included to 
>   indicate modifiers such as *Shift*, *Alt* or *Ctrl*.  The 
>   default is *off*.

When you turn the option *on*, then `tmux` will pass-through unchanged the special keys that match that pattern:

```
set-option -gw xterm-keys on
```

However, you may notice that `1` is not mentioned in the source code for tmux.  As `tmux` reads the keys (before deciding what to do with them), it saves the modifier.  It cannot distinguish between a `1` and no modifier at all.  That makes sense because `xterm` would not distinguish the two, either.

In any case, xterm would normally not send *anything* for a shifted-insert key.  You could force it to do this using the `translations` resource, but according to the [xterm manual](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#h3-Default-Key-Bindings), a shifted-insert causes it to insert the selected text (i.e., *paste*):

```
Shift <KeyPress> Insert:insert-selection(SELECT, CUT_BUFFER0) \n\
```